# How to compute high dimensional regression statistics

Tags: r, regression

I have a model below

```
A = matrix(1, nrow = 400, ncol = 400)
A = 0.5**abs(row(A) - col(A))
X=mvtnorm::rmvnorm(300,mean=rep(0,400),sigma=A)))  
Y=X[,6]+X[,12]+X[,15]+X[,20]+0.7*pnorm(X[,1])*rnorm(300) 
df <- data.frame(Y, X)
```

and i want to fit least squares lasso to it. I need to summarise the following:

1. The percentage of times including X6, X12, X15 and X20 in simulation runs
2. The proportion of simulation runs including X1

How can i calculate 1. and 2.? The results should be  100% and 6%.

```
av_model_size <- c(NULL)
a1 <- c(NULL)
a2 <- c(NULL)
for (i in 1:100) {
  lassocv <- glmnet::cv.glmnet(X, Y, alpha = 1)
  modelcv <- glmnet::glmnet(X, Y, alpha = 1, lambda = lassocv$lambda.min, standardize = TRUE)
  lasso.coef <- modelcv$beta
  av_model_size[[i]] <- sum(lasso.coef!=0)
  a1[[i]] <- sum(lasso.coef[6] != 0 && lasso.coef[12] != 0 && lasso.coef[15] != 0 && lasso.coef[20] != 0)
  a2[[i]] <- sum(lasso.coef[1] != 0)
}
```

mean(ams)

Comment: Are you struggling with the procedure in general, or with a precise step? It sounds like all you need to do is to wrap your code in a loop of sorts and collect the coefficients for the relevant Xs, and then count how often they are different from 0.

Comment: Yeah the overall procedure, how would i do that?

Comment: As I said, you wrap your code into a loop to repeat it 1000 times, and each time, you store the coefficients of your final model. Then you count how often they are different from 0.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions - I have tried to implement repeated simulations however the values are very low when i take mean(a1), mean(a2)

Comment: ok, see my answer below, which was a bit too long for a comment here. @Btzzzz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to include the data generation in your simulation process. As you have outlined your example, you are executing the functions on the same set of data. Consider the following:

```
set.seed(42)

get_simulated_data <- function(){
  A = matrix(1, nrow = 400, ncol = 400)
  A = 0.5**abs(row(A) - col(A))
  X = mvtnorm::rmvnorm(300,mean=rep(0,400),sigma=A)
  Y = X[,6]+X[,12]+X[,15]+X[,20]+0.7*pnorm(X[,1])*rnorm(300)
  dat <- list(Y=Y, X=X)
  return(dat)
}

get_coefficients <- function(){
  dat <- get_simulated_data()
  lassocv <- glmnet::cv.glmnet(dat$X, dat$Y, alpha = 1)
  modelcv <- glmnet::glmnet(dat$X, dat$Y, alpha = 1, lambda = lassocv$lambda.min, standardize = TRUE)
  return(modelcv$beta)
}


out <- do.call(cbind, lapply(1:100, function(i) get_coefficients()))

rowMeans(out[c("V1", "V6", "V12", "V15", "V20"),] == 0)
  V1   V6  V12  V15  V20 
0.93 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
```